# what function does nothing in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

what is the command that when we have IF case and if we want to do nothing in that case we can put that command there.

Comment: You just changed your whole question. Write a new one and leave the other as is.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a "do nothing" command. You should just negate your `if`:

```
if (x > 9) {
   // nothing
} else {
   // do stuff
}
```

Becomes:

```
if (x <= 9) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Regarding your second (edited question):

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
          if ((i % 2) != 0)
               continue;

          NSLog( @"i = %i", i);
}
```

The `continue` does of course work and will start the next loop cycle.

For future questions: Don't edit your question to a completely new one. Ask a new question!